# How to delete the row that has least value in a specific column if group by count of the column is greater than 1

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a table like given below name recomendation

[image]

I want to delete all the rows where `cnt` has the minimum value and there exist multiple records of `ID_recipient`.

If there is a single record of `ID_recipient` it shouldn't get deleted whatever the `cnt` value may be.

The ones highlighted in blue are the records that must stay.

I tried:

```
DELETE from table where( 
    SELECT DISTINCT(A.ID_recipient), DISTINCT(A.cnt) FROM (
          SELECT  MIN(cnt) as cnt FROM recomendation_table_ID_recipient GROUP BY ID_recipient HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) as A);
```

which is not working.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query), and note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: I created a db-fiddle with some test data, but as @Strawberry pointed out, you should do this if you are looking to get help in the future.

Comment: I'm sure you can do it all for the OP next time too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use 2 dimensions you have to use IN clause.

Your subquerys doesn't make much sense, so you should test this first, or post data with wanted example

```
DELETE from recomendation_table_ID_recipient where (ID_recipient,cnt) IN ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT A.ID_recipient, A.cnt FROM (
          SELECT ID_recipient, MIN(cnt) as cnt FROM recomendation_table_ID_recipient GROUP BY ID_recipient HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) as A);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete t1 from recomendation_table_ID_recipient t1 join (
    select ID_recipient, min(cnt) as cnt from recomendation_table_ID_recipient
    group by ID_recipient
    having count(*) > 1
) t2 on t1.ID_recipient = t2.ID_recipient and t1.cnt = t2.cnt;
```

[See db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3FqEMUVu8UBtGB717QWTjZ/1)